# required and additionalProperties is not working for jsonschema module Python

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have following code :

```
from jsonschema import validate
schema_data = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
        "additional" : {"type" : "number"},
        },
    "required": ["price", "name", "additional"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}

json_data = {"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 34.99, "new": 90}
```

This should give me an error for both `required` and `additionalProperties` as `additional` is not present in `json_data` and `new` is not present in `schema_data`. **But script is not giving any error**.

Do I need some extra to install? I am having following configuration:

```
Python 2.7.12,
jsonschema==3.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
six==1.12.0
pyrsistent==0.14.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run below command for getting error

```
validate(json_data, schema_data)
```

So first you'll get error

```
'additional' is a required property
```

After fixing you'll get error for

```
Additional properties are not allowed ('new' was unexpected)
```